# Set XAML-defined content to PivotItem

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have XAML-defined Content for PivotItem in App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cd">
     <!-- Some grids -->
</DataTemplate>
```

I also have defined Pivot:

```
<controls:Pivot>
    <controls:PivotItem Header="xxx">
        <!-- Irrelevant -->
    </controls:PivotItem>

    <controls:PivotItem x:Name="MyItem" />
</controls:Pivot>
```

And when I try to set predefined content to PivotItem - nothing happens (I can't see content set).

```
MyItem.Content = (Application.Current as App).Resources["cd"] as DataTemplate;
```

So, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource cd}" Content="" />
```

might work. DataTemplate's are never set as children, they are set into special properties such as ContentTemplate.

Since it's probably a little inconvenient and weird for what you're doing, you should use UserControls. The normal way to use them is the per-file approach though, by adding a new "Silverlight User Control" with the wizard.

The place where you really want to use DataTemplates is when you use lists of things that need databinding.